# Count the number of customers with at least one presence in each of the last 3 weeks in Oracle 21c

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello I'm coming back to you again and maybe you can help me this time too.

Starting from another post of mine and taking inspiration from here https://oracle-base.com//articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2
I managed to find a solution but I would like to believe there are other methods because if I had to go back 9,10 weeks it would not have been performant at all.

I create db fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/h1zmicL7 with ddl and dml respectively my solution. I would like someone to help me with a solution using connect by clause starting from my solution or any other solution more performant.

In the table the column "expected_output" have the final result and is added manually by me.

I m using Oracle 21c.

I will explain what the logic is here and how it should be calculated for each client much more clearly - I need all the rows in the present case, there are 21.

Why does client 1 have the first 1 in week 4 - because we look in week 1 to see if we have something in the back for client 1 and we don't, so 0, then in week 2 we also look back and see that he is present only once but we need 3 presence, so still 0, then in week 3 the same, we see 2 presence in the back so still 0 and in week 4 we have the first 1 because this client has
3 consecutive presence in the last 3 weeks and that is important to be consecutive.

The column weeknum is to_number(to_char(data,'ww')).

Why client 1 has in the week 6 a 3, because we look back at every 3 weeks so in week 6 client 1 have at least 1 presence in each consecutive weeks no gaps in  1,2,3(at week 4 first 1) and  2,3,4(at week 5 another 1 and plus 1 he have 2) and week 3,4,5 so in week 6 he had a 3.

Why client 1 has in week 8 a 0 and not a 3 because at week 6 he had a 3? Because again we look back at the last 3 weeks (5,6,7)and we see client 1 with at least 1 presence in a ride
in the week 5 and 6- and  no presence in week 7 so here he don t have 3 consecutive presences in the last 3 weeks so we need 0.

Like this is for all the clients.

Thank you

```
Ride  Client    Data         Weeknum     Expected_output
1       1   02-JAN-2023         1               0
2       1   05-JAN-2023         1               0
3       3   06-JAN-2023         1               0
4       1   11-JAN-2023         2               0
5       2   12-JAN-2023         2               0
6       1   16-JAN-2023         3               0
7       2   19-JAN-2023         3               0
8       1   24-JAN-2023         4               1
9       2   24-JAN-2023         4               0
10      1   30-JAN-2023         5               2
11      2   02-FEB-2023         5               1
12      2   08-FEB-2023         6               2
13      1   09-FEB-2023         6               3
14      3   15-FEB-2023         7               0
15      2   16-FEB-2023         7               3
16      3   17-FEB-2023         7               0
17      1   21-FEB-2023         8               0
18      3   22-FEB-2023         8               0
19      3   23-FEB-2023         8               0
20      3   28-FEB-2023         9               0
21      3   07-MAR-2023        10               1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you particularly want a solution using `CONNECT BY` then (however, I would expect a solution using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` or only analytic functions to be more efficient):

```sql
SELECT client,
       weeknum,
       ride,
       data,
       expected_output,
       GREATEST(weeknum - CONNECT_BY_ROOT(weeknum) - 2, 0) AS output
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         CASE
         WHEN weeknum <= LAG(weeknum) OVER (PARTITION BY client ORDER BY data) + 1
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1
         END AS start_week,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY client ORDER BY data) AS rn
  FROM   prob p
)
START WITH
        start_week = 1
CONNECT BY
        PRIOR rn + 1 = rn
AND     PRIOR client = client
AND     start_week = 0
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| CLIENT | WEEKNUM | RIDE | DATA | EXPECTED_OUTPUT | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2023-01-11 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 6 | 2023-01-16 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 8 | 2023-01-24 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 10 | 2023-01-30 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 6 | 13 | 2023-02-09 00:00:00 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 8 | 17 | 2023-02-21 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 | 2023-01-12 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 7 | 2023-01-19 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 9 | 2023-01-24 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 11 | 2023-02-02 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 | 12 | 2023-02-08 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 7 | 15 | 2023-02-16 00:00:00 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2023-01-06 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 7 | 14 | 2023-02-15 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 7 | 16 | 2023-02-17 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 8 | 18 | 2023-02-22 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 8 | 19 | 2023-02-23 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 9 | 20 | 2023-02-28 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 10 | 21 | 2023-03-07 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2b73l6RC)

Answer (score 1):

First try:

```
select client, weeknum, expected_output,
    row_number() over(partition by client, rn
        order by weeknum) as calc_output 
from (
    select client, weeknum, expected_output, nothers,
        weeknum - row_number() over(partition by client order by weeknum) as rn
        from (
        select p1.client, p1.weeknum, p1.expected_output,
            count(distinct p2.weeknum) as nothers
        from prob p1
        join prob p2 on p1.client = p2.client and p2.weeknum between p1.weeknum - 3 and p1.weeknum - 1
        group by p1.client, p1.weeknum, p1.expected_output -- having( count(distinct p2.weeknum) >= 3 )
    )
    where nothers >= 3
)
order by client, weeknum desc
;


client weeknum expected_output calc_output
    1   6   3   3
    1   5   2   2
    1   4   1   1
    2   7   3   3
    2   6   2   2
    2   5   1   1
    3   10  1   1
```

Comment: p3consulting Thank you so much for trying to help me and solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT client,
       weeknum,
       ride,
       data,
       expected_output,
       GREATEST(weeknum - first_weeknum - 2, 0) AS output
FROM   prob p
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY client
  ORDER BY weeknum
  MEASURES
    FIRST(weeknum) AS first_weeknum
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ((first_week same_week*) (next_week same_week*)*)
  DEFINE
    same_week AS weeknum = PREV(weeknum),
    next_week AS weeknum = PREV(weeknum) + 1
)
```

In earlier versions, you can use analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT client,
       weeknum,
       ride,
       data,
       expected_output,
       GREATEST(
         weeknum
         - LAST_VALUE(new_weeknum) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
             PARTITION BY client
             ORDER BY data
           )
         - 2,
         0
       ) AS output
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         CASE
         WHEN weeknum <= LAG(weeknum) OVER (PARTITION BY client ORDER BY data) + 1
         THEN NULL
         ELSE weeknum
         END AS new_weeknum
  FROM   prob p
);
```

Which, for the sample data, both output:

| CLIENT | WEEKNUM | RIDE | DATA | EXPECTED_OUTPUT | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2023-01-11 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 6 | 2023-01-16 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 8 | 2023-01-24 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 10 | 2023-01-30 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 6 | 13 | 2023-02-09 00:00:00 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 8 | 17 | 2023-02-21 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 | 2023-01-12 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 7 | 2023-01-19 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 9 | 2023-01-24 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 11 | 2023-02-02 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 | 12 | 2023-02-08 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 7 | 15 | 2023-02-16 00:00:00 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2023-01-06 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 7 | 16 | 2023-02-17 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 7 | 14 | 2023-02-15 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 8 | 18 | 2023-02-22 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 8 | 19 | 2023-02-23 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 9 | 20 | 2023-02-28 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 10 | 21 | 2023-03-07 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wwxoQgW8)

Comment: MT0 Thank you so much for taking time and providing a solution.Could this problem solved using connect by clause?Thank you

Comment: @Florin Probably, but it is likely to be much less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
 with flo as(
select a.*, 
case when mod(weeknum-lag(weeknum,3)over(partition by client order by weeknum),3)=0
then 1 else 0 end as consec_chk
from( 
select a.*, row_number()over(partition by client, weeknum order by weeknum)as rn 
from prob1 a
)a
where rn=1
)
select ride, client, data, weeknum, expected_output, case when consec_chk =1 then 
row_number()over(partition by client, consec_chk order by weeknum) else 0 end as output
from flo ;
```